# Drawing from a set of Poisson variables and adding them up

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

I have $k$ Poisson RV, each with mean $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_i, \dots, \lambda_k$.

I am drawing without replacement $h$ many out of them.

I then add up the realization of all their outcomes, and wonder about that distribution.

Here's what I have so far. The probability of drawing the combination of any 3 RV in particular order is $(k-h)!/k!$. Denote $I = \{1, \dots k\}$

$$ Prob(i_1 + \dots + i_h = m) = \frac{(k-h)!}{k!} \sum_{i_1 \in I} \sum_{i_2 \in I \setminus i_1} \dots \sum_{i_h \in I \setminus \{i_1, \dots i_{h-1}\}}  e^{-(\lambda_{i_1} + \dots \lambda_{i_h})}(\lambda_{i_1} + \dots \lambda_{i_h})^m \frac{1}{m!} $$

While this expression is good at explaining what I'm after, it's not useful for computing the sum and hopefully finding a simpler expression.

Can anyone drop some pointers on an alternative and hopefully better approach?

Comment: As a start: If $X_i \sim \mathsf{Pois}(\lambda_i),$ for $i = 1, \dots, n,$ are independent then $T = \sum_i X_i \sim \mathsf{Pois}(\sum_i \lambda_i).$ From there, googling 'mixture of Poissons' and 'random sum of random variables' may be helpful.

Comment: I think $\binom{k}{h}$ should be in the denominator and the $\sum_{i_1}\ldots\sum_{i_2}$ you wrote is incorrect as it contains redundant combinations. Each possible combination of $i_1, \ldots, i_h$ should be counted only once and I do not believe that the resulting summation can be simplified any further unless all $\lambda_i$'s are equal. Also, it's $e^{-(\lambda_{i_1} + \ldots + \lambda_{i_h})}$ not $e^{\lambda_{i_1} + \ldots + \lambda_{i_h}}$.